# Как отправить стикер с помощью телеграм-бота C#

Tags: c#, .net

Народ, расскажите, как отправить стикер с помощью телеграм бота, когда выполняется определённое условие.
Документацию прочёл, но не пойму, как отправить стикер. Когда я программировал бота на python 3 там всё было изи:

```
sticker = open(path)
bot.SendSticker(message.Chat.Id, sticker)
```

но когда я взялся за разработку бота на C#, то возникла проблема:

```
else if (message.Text == "Привет")
            {
                var sti = File.Open("C:/Users/Виталик/source/repos/ТелегаБот/bin/Debug/hello1.wepb");
                await bot.SendStickerAsync(message.Chat.Id, sti);
            }
```

[image: Описание ошибки]

Что делать с этим? Как заставить бота отправить стикер?

Comment: У вас ошибка говорит "Ей, я не знаю от куда ты хочешь взять `File`, определись уже!". Другими словами у вас подключено 2 пространства имен, которые содержат класс с одним и тем же названием. Задавайте пространство имен явно тогда перед вызовом, либо переопределяйте в Using из какого namespace брать класс.

Comment: `var sti = System.IO.File.Open...` либо `FileStream sti = File.Open...`